# How can I change input value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio1" class="radio" / value="1" />
```

I tried using jQuery:

```
$('#radio1').value=1;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: use `$('#radio1').val('1')`

Comment: using `/` in `input` tag is incorrect - remove it `/`. And to change value try `$('#radio1').val(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to show OP the correct HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio1" class="radio" value="1" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#radio1').val(1);
```